# Saving last 10 digits of string

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using an api to save mobile numbers of my users to databases

```
public function save_user_phonebook_record($data)
{
    $mobile=str_replace('+','0',$data['mobile']);
    $mobile=str_replace(' ','',$mobile);
    $mobile=substr($mobile, -10);
    $params = array(':mobile' => $mobile, ':user_id' => $data['user_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends where mobile=:mobile AND user_id=:user_id";
    $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
        $res=$row;
    endwhile;
    if(count($res)<1)
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO friends (user_id, name, mobile) 
        VALUES(:user_id, :name, :mobile)';
        $params =(array(
            ':user_id' => $data['user_id'],
            ':name' => $data['name'],
            ':mobile' => $data['mobile']
        ));
        parent::query($sql, $params) or die(parent::$dbh->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

API USED

```
$client->save_phonebook(array('key'=>$api_key, 'user_id'=>'25349', 'phonebook'=>json_encode(array(array('name'=>'XXXXX Jain',"mobile"=>"+919876543210"),array('name'=>'xxxxxx Verma',"mobile"=>"09876543210")))));
```

Mobile number stored in table mobile is saved as `+919812345678,09876543210,` though i have put `$mobile=substr($mobile, -10);`  to save only the last 10 digits of the number but does not seem to work for some reason

Comment: its working [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DknD1)

Comment: As a side note, replacing `+` by `0` is something you probably don't want to do! There is a difference between national numbers which may legitimately start with zero (e.g. in Germany I would write `01521234567`) and international numbers (e.g. the same number in international format, with Germany's prefix, would be `+491521234567`)! The `+` stands for the "international call prefix" which is different depending on the country *from* where you call (not *to* where). In many European countries, it is `00` for example, so you could dial `00491521234567`, but others are different, e.g. `011`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change here, replace `$data['mobile']` to `$mobile`

```
$params =(array(
            ':user_id' => $data['user_id'],
            ':name' => $data['name'],
            ':mobile' => $mobile
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) on `$mobile`

Use `$mobile` instead of `$data['mobile']`

OR, do `substr()` on `$data['mobile']`

```
$data['mobile'] = substr($data['mobile'], -10);
```